# Unit Test Explorer in Visual Studio 11 fails with reference to the Microsoft Smooth Streaming Client SDK Beta 1 assembly

Tags: visual-studio, mstest, windows-8, smooth-streaming

Having a reference to the Microsoft.Media.SmoothStreaming.dll in a Metro Style App project, then attempting to run tests from a separate Unit Test project that references the Metro Style App assembly does not work in Visual Studio 11 (Ultimate Beta Version 11.0.50323.1 QRELB), even with the processor types both set to either x86 or x64 in the Debug compilation configuration.

The platform target of the Metro Style App must be set to either x86 or x64 (Any CPU won't work with the SmoothStreaming SDK assembly).  The Unit Test project target must match the setting of the Metro Style App when it contains a reference to the Metro Style App assembly, otherwise you get the following error:

"Error  1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "%APPROOT%\bin\x86\Debug\UVerseApp.exe", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project"

When both are set to x64, the solution compiles and runs fine but the Unit Test Explorer will not discover any of the tests from the unit test project, so you can't run them or even see them.

When both are set to x86, the solution builds fine and the Unit Test Explorer properly displays all tests.  However, if you attempt to run any of the tests, you encounter an application error in vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe every time.  The Metro app will still run fine - this only happens when you attempt to run or debug tests methods using Unit Test Explorer.

Is this a known issue and/or are there any possible workarounds?

Comment: This problem is not only related to that SDK; The vstest framework doesn't like testing assemblies linked to native code, and often crashes when doing so. Unfortunately, I did not find out how to solve this yet...